# Illustrating Edward Nelson's Worldview with Nonstandard Models of Arithmetic

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory, foundations, constructive-mathematics, ultrafinitism

Mathematician Edward Nelson is known for his extreme views on the foundations of mathematics, variously described as "ultrafintism" or "strict finitism" (Nelson's preferred term), which came into the split light recently because of his claim, quickly recanted, of proving $PA$ inconsistent (but he's still working on it).  He believes in Robinson Arithmetic, but not the induction schema of Peano Arithmetic (although he does accept weak forms of induction interpretable in Robinson's $Q$, like induction for bounded formulas; see his book [Predicative Arithmetic](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/books/pa.pdf)).  He even believes that exponentiation is not total!  Here is a quote explaining his viewpoint:

“The intuition that the set of all subsets of a finite set is finite—or more generally, that if $A$ and $B$ are finite sets, then so is the set $B^A$ of all functions from $A$ to $B$—is a questionable intuition. Let $A$ be the set of some $5000$ spaces for symbols on a blank sheet of typewriter paper, and let $B$ be the set of some $80$ symbols of a typewriter; then perhaps $B^A$ is infinite. Perhaps it is even incorrect to think of $B^A$ as being a set. To do so is to postulate an entity, the set of all possible typewritten pages, and then to ascribe some kind of reality to this entity—for example, by asserting that one can in principle survey each possible typewritten page. But perhaps it is simply not so. Perhaps there is no such number as $80^{5000}$; perhaps it is always possible to write a new and different page.”

He believes that finite numbers are closed under addition and multiplication, but not exponentiation: he thinks you can have two numbers, like $80$ and $5000$, which are both finite, but where $80^{5000}$ in infinitely large!

My question is, can we illustrate this view using a nonstandard model of arithmetic?  Specifically, how would we construct a nonstandard model of $Q$, containing an initial segment closed under successor, addition, and multiplication, but not exponentiation?  Preferably, I'd like a computable nonstandard model.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

EDIT: As @JoelDavidHamkins pointed out, exponentiation need not be total in a model of $Q$, so such a model wouldn't illustrate the phenomenon Edward Nelson believes is possible, of the exponentiation of finite numbers being infinite.  So let me clarify: I'm looking for a computable nonstandard model of $Q$ + "exponentiation is total", such that the model has an initial segment closed under successor, addition, and multiplication, but not exponentiation.

EDIT 2: @EmilJeřábek has pointed out that different formulations of "exponentiation is total" in the language of arithmetic aren't provably equivalent in $Q$.  How you formalize this assertion doesn't really concern me, so rather than talk about models of $Q$ + "exponentiation is total", let me talk about models $M$ of $Q$ equipped with a binary operation on $M$ that satisfies the basic properties of exponentiation: $a^{b+c} = a^b a^c$, $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$, $a^1 = a$, $a^{0} = 1$, and $0^b = 0$.  I also want addition and multiplication to be commutative and associative, multiplication to distribute over addition, and addition to obey the cancellation property that $a + c = b + c$ implies $a = b$.  An example of a computable nonstandard model of $Q$ that satisfies at least these properties of addition and multiplication is the set of polynomials $\{P = a_nx^n + \ldots + a_0 \in \Bbb Z[x] , a_n > 0 \}$, together with $0$, with polynomial addition and multiplication, and the successor just involving adding $1$.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but in this article: https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/papers/warn.pdf Nelson gives a mathematical argument in favor of his view.

Comment: Yes, I've read this, and most other papers by Nelson on the subject.

Comment: Regarding your latest edit, see the comment I posted on my answer.

Comment: *What* is exponentiation? There are various reasonable ways of defining (the graph of) exponentiation in sufficiently strong theories such as $I\Delta_0$, but they are going to be neither mutually equivalent nor well-behaved in $Q$ (or in the kind of theories that have computable nonstandard models). You need to state exactly what you want.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek I want a nonstandard model of $Q$ along with a binary operation ^ that satisfies the usual properties of exponentiation: $a^{b+c} = a^b a^c$, $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$, $a^1 = a$, $a^0 = 1$, and $0^b = 0$.  And I want addition and multiplication to satisfy the usual properties of associativity, commutativity, distributivity, and the cancellation law.

Answer (score 37):

Thanks to Timothy Chow for informing me of this discussion.

To avoid vagueness, let Q* be Q with the usual relativization schemata adjoined. Construct a formal system F by adjoining an unary predicate symbol $\psi$, the axiom $\psi(0)$, and the rule of inference: from $\rm\psi(a)$ infer $\rm\psi(Sa)$ (for any term a). I think this is an adequate formalization of the concept of an "actual number". Is $\psi(80^{5000})$ a theorem of F? I see no reason to believe so. Of course, one can arithmetize F in various theories, even Q*, and prove a formula $\exists p[p \hbox{ is an arithmetized proof in F of }
`\psi(80^{5000})\hbox{'}]$, but to conclude from this that there is a proof in F itself of $\psi(80^{5000})$ appears to me to be unjustified.

Contrast F with the theory T obtained by adjoining to Q* a unary predicate symbol $\phi$ and the two axioms $\phi(0)$ and $\phi(0)\;\&\;\forall x'[\phi(x')\to\phi({\rm S}x')]\to\phi(x)$. Then one can easily prove in T $\phi(80^{5000})$ or even
$\phi(80^{5000...^{5000}})$.
The ellipsis means that the iterated exponential term is actually written down.

Comment: To be clear, you also see no reason to believe that $\psi(80\cdot80\cdots80)$ (where we actually write down five thousand 80's) is a theorem of F, right?

Comment: @Timothy Chow. Yes.

Comment: @Timothy Chow. I should add that since F proves $80^{5000}=80\cdot80\cdots80$ this is automatic.

Comment: Is there a least i such that you see no reason to believe that  ψ(80^i) is a theorem of F?

Comment: @abo. No, there is no least $i$ such that I see no reason to believe that $\psi(80^i)$ is a theroem of F.

Comment: @EN.  Why not? For example it would take only around 13 tries to bifurcate 5000 successfully. First question: do you see no reason to believe that ψ(80^i) is a theorem of F if i = 2500? If you answer yes, second question has i = 1250; and if you answer no, second question has i = 3750. etc. Is it a question of vagueness, like 5000 hairs is a lot of hair, but you would say there is no least i such that i hairs is a lot of hairs because "lot" is vague?

Comment: Also, if I may, one other line of question (I think this interests many many more people than myself, so it is why I am presuming to take up your time).  Is the notion of "actual number" different from the notion of "natural number"? If the answer is yes, does induction hold for the actual numbers? If the answer is no, why the use of "actual" instead of "natural"?

Comment: @abo. You seem to be arguing in ordinary language that $\exists p[p \text{ is an arithmetized proof in F of } \psi(80^{5000})]$. No dispute about that. But the reasoning cannot be expressed in F. I fear this is getting way off topic for MathOverflow.

Comment: @EN.  Many thanks for your comments.

Comment: @EdwardNelson Do you believe for all $x$ and $y$, if $\psi(x)$ and $\psi(y)$ are theorems of F, then $\psi(x \cdot y)$ is a theorem of F?  It's my understanding that you do believe that, since you view multiplication as total.  If I'm right about that, then why can't you apply the above statement 5000 times to conclude that $\psi(80\cdot 80 ... 80)$ is a theorem of F?

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan I believe that for $\phi$ but not for $\psi$.

Comment: @EdwardNelson So you don't believe that "actual numbers" (i.e. numbers for which $\psi$ holds) are closed under multiplication.  Do you at least believe that they're closed under addition?  If you don't think they're closed under addition, that means that it's possible for there to be some numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $\psi(x)$ and $\psi(y)$ but not $\psi(x+y)$, but can't you write out $x$ and $y$ as sums of the form $1 + 1 + ... + 1$, and then repeatedly use the fact that actual numbers are closed under successor to conclude that $\psi((1 + 1 + ... + 1) + (1 + 1 + ... + 1))$?

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan If I believed that, then, applying that reasoning a billion times, I would believe that $\psi(2^{2^{1000000000}})$ is a theorem, but I don't. Abstract arguments about a formal system are really arguments about its arithmetization.

Comment: @EdwardNelson So you believe that it's possible (or at least conceivable) that you could write down a long string of 1's (with plus signs in between) and break it up into two substrings, such that the first substring corresponds to an actual number and the second substring corresponds to an actual number, but the whole string doesn't correspond to an actual number?  If that's what you believe, then why do people always say "Nelson believes that addition and multiplication are total, but exponentiation is not"?  Are they talking about your beliefs concerning $\phi$ rather than $\psi$?

Comment: @EdwardNelson Sorry, I had forgotten about the role of relativization schemes in your work.  So let me ask you this: using the notion of actual number, in your work you define a notion of additionable number which is closed under addition, and then a notion of multiplicable number which is closed under multiplication.  So then isn't $80^{5000}$ a multiplicable number, since you can use the fact that multiplicable numbers are closed under multiplication $5000$ times?

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan Q* proves that addition and multiplication are total, but does not prove that exponentiation is total. The situation is different with F and $\psi$: a rule of inference is far more restrictive than an implication, and F does dot prove that if $\psi(x)$ then $\psi({\rm S}x)$.

Comment: @EdwardNelson I don't see why F does not prove that $\psi(x)$ implies $\psi({\rm S}x)$.  $Q$ includes the propositional calculus, so if we assume $\psi(x)$ and then apply the rule, we get $\psi({\rm S}x)$, which by the deduction theorem allows you to conclude that $\psi(x)$ implies $\psi({\rm S}x)$.  But even if F does not prove that $\psi(x)$ implies $\psi({\rm S}x)$, do you at least believe that it's true, or are all your beliefs concerning $\psi$ restricted to what can be proven in $F$?

Comment: @Keshav Srinivasan The formal system F is not a theory, and the deduction theorem does not hold. I don't understand what it being true could mean. Perhaps we should not continue this lengthy discussion on MathOverflow. Many thanks for your interest.

Comment: I think Edward Nelson has tried to formalize the "marks on paper" problem. Just because we can define [Ackermann(1000,1000)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) with a few symbols does not mean we can really put Ackermann(1000,1000) marks on a piece of paper.

Answer (score 28):

If you are really satisfied with a model only of the theory $Q$, then you should be prepared for a bad situation, for this is an extremely weak theory. In fact one can make a computable model simply by adding a single new point at infinity, forming the structure $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ with the usual arithmetic on the finite part, and defining $n+\infty=\infty=\infty+n$ for any finite $n$, and $n\cdot\infty=\infty=\infty\cdot n$ for any finite nonzero $n$. This silly model, unfortunately, satisfies $Q$, which goes to show you how weak $Q$ is as far as determining the usual theory of arithmetic: it doesn't even prove  $\forall x\ x+1\neq x$. Similar models can be constructed by adding two points at infinity, where multiplication is not commutative and other unusual arithmetic situations arise. So $Q$ is a very weak theory having computable nonstandard models.

As you strengthen the theory that you want, you will run into the Tennenbaum phenomenon, which asserts that there is no computable nonstandard model of PA. Indeed, if $\langle N,+,\cdot\rangle$ is a nonstandard model of PA, then neither $+$ nor $\cdot$ is computable. I noticed that there has been some work on [The limits of the Tennenbaum phenomenon](http://projecteuclid.org/DPubS?verb=Display&version=1.0&service=UI&handle=euclid.ndjfl/1039700698&page=record) for weak theories, and I'm not sure where the boundary lies.

Meanwhile, it is easy to find cuts in any nonstandard model of PA, which are closed under addition and multiplication, but not exponentiation. Every nonstandard model of PA has unboundedly many such proper initial segments like this. For example, if $\cal{N}$ is a nonstandard model of PA, let $m$ be any nonstandard element, and let $I$ be the collection of numbers $n$ in the model $\cal{N}$ below $m^k$ for some standard $k$. This collection is closed under addition and multiplication in $\cal{N}$, but not exponentiation, essentially because $m^k\cdot m^s=m^{k+s}$. So the model $\langle I,+,\cdot,0,1,\lt\rangle$ thinks exponentiation is not total, although its addition and multiplication properties are very nice, since it is an initial segment of a model of PA. I'm not sure whether one can find a computable such model; the question is whether the Tennenbaum phenomenon applies, and I think it likely does.

Comment: You forgot a comma in the Tennenbaum phenomenon paragraph (the definition of the non-standard model).

Comment: There are various “Tennenbaum phenomena” (there are no nonstandard recursive models, every nonstandard model has a nonstandard cut satisfying PA, the additive reduct of the model is recursively saturated, the real closure of the model is recursively saturated) whose boundaries may somewhat differ, but if we stick to the basic property of having nonstandard recursive models, the strongest theory known to have such models is IOpen + Bézout property + there are infinitely many primes http://www.lc08.iam.unibe.ch/program/mohsenipour.pdf , while on the other hand, there are no nonstandard recursive

Comment: models of $IE_1$, or of just about any fragment of bounded arithmetic in Buss’s framework with some form of sharply bounded induction (say, $\mathit{BASIC}+\Sigma^b_0\text-\mathit{LIND}$).

Comment: Editing suggestion: I found the order of quantifiers confusing in the definition of $I$ (specifically, that $k$ could depend on $n$.) You mean $\{ n : \exists k \ \mbox{such that}  \ k\ \mbox{is standard and}\ n<m^k \}$, right?

Comment: There are plenty of non-pathological non-standard models of $Q$.  For instance, $\{P = a_nx^n + \ldots + a_0 \in \Bbb Z[x] , a_n > 0 \}$ with polynomial addition and multiplication, and the successor just involving adding 1, is a computable nonstandard model of $Q$.

Comment: Yes, @David, that is what I meant.

Comment: Keshav, I agree that we have plenty of models of $Q$. My point was only that this is the wrong theory, since it is too weak. Meanwhile, you can't get computable models of the stronger theories we like, because the Tennenbaum phenomenon kicks in already quite low.

Comment: Whether it's the "wrong" theory or not, I'm still interested in getting a computable nonstandard model to illustrate Nelson's viewpoint, so I'm fine if it's only a model of $Q$.  The polynomial ring example, for instance, would do just fine; it doesn't have the pathological properties that models of $Q$ can potentially have.  And as @EmilJerabek pointed out, we can even go a little stronger than $Q$ and still get computable models.  Open induction is an example.  In any case, do you have any idea of how I can construct a computable model of $Q$ that meets my conditions?

Comment: My perspective on $Q$ is that it is a weak theory that is sufficient to support the argument of the incompleteness theorem. Is anyone proposing that we consider $Q$ as expressing our fundamental theory of arithmetic? I don't believe that this is how Nelsen views $Q$. This is the sense in which it is the wrong theory, and your preference for non-"pathological" models is of course another way of saying you want a stronger theory.  Meanwhile, we do have several examples of computable models of $Q$. The polynomial model has a computable presentation,  by coding polynomials with finite strings.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins Yes, there are examples of computable models of $Q$, but do you know of any computable model of $Q$ that satisfies my condition of having an initial segment closed under successor, addition, and multiplication, but not exponentiation?  For starters, does the polynomial model satisfy it?

Comment: I think that you need to add $0$ to your polynomial model, since it is not included in the definition you gave, and then yes, this will be a model of $Q$ closed under addition and multiplication, but it has no function obeying the expected properties of exponentiation. e.g. which polynomial is $x^x$ to be? While it is clear what "being closed under exponentiation" means in an initial segment of a model of PA, since we can define exponentiation there, we don't have a concept of "exponentiation" in any model of $Q$, and so one should be more explicit about what is meant by your phrase.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins You're right, let me clarify: I want a computable nonstandard model of $Q$ + "exponentiation is total", such that the model has an initial segment closed under successor, addition, and multiplication, but not exponentiation.

Comment: It seems one can do that as follows: the model is $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty_1,\infty_2\}$, with a "small" infinity $\infty_1$ and "large" infinity $\infty_2$, so $n+\infty_1=n\cdot\infty_1=\infty_1$ and $n+\infty_2=n\cdot\infty_2=\infty_2$, but $\infty_1+\infty_2=\infty_1\cdot\infty_2=\infty_2$ etc. Now define exponentation as norml, but have $x^{\infty_1}=\infty_2$ for any $x>1$. I believe this satisfies $Q$ plus the basic recursive definition of exponentiation.

Comment: ...Meanwhile, there is an initial segment, namely $\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty_1\}$, which is not closed under exponentiation, but is closed under addition and multiplication. If you object to this model as "pathological", then I reiterate my remark that you aren't really interested in models of $Q$, and instead want a much stronger theory.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins You're right, I do consider that model pathological, but that doesn't mean I want a much stronger theory than $Q$.  I just want a model that's not pathological, something like the polynomial model, i.e. something that satisfies associativity and commutativity for addition and multiplication, distributivity of multiplication over addition, and the cancellation law for addition ($x + z = y + z$ implies $x = y$).  That's a very small extension of $Q$, and that wouldn't affect the existence of computable models at all; just look at the polynomial model.

Answer (score 21):

Other people have answered your question as stated, but let me address what I think is your real underlying question, which is whether one can construct a conventional mathematical structure that has all the properties that Nelson wants to attribute to the natural numbers.  I think that this is fundamentally impossible, because conventional mathematics isn't capable of being *vague* in the requisite manner.  No infinite set can properly represent what Nelson believes in since he doesn't believe in infinite sets.  But no finite set can either, because finite sets have sharp boundaries.  There isn't any specific integer $n$ that Nelson will absolutely affirm such that he will absolutely deny $n+1$.

In my opinion the most promising avenue is not to try to model Nelson's integers directly, but instead to model *Nelson himself*, or more precisely the kinds of statements that Nelson is willing to affirm.  In doing so, we're free to use infinite sets or anything else that *we* believe in.  As a first crude approximation, I can imagine defining a probability distribution $P$ on sentences of first-order arithmetic where $P(S)$ represents the probability that Nelson will affirm $S$.  I could also imagine coming up with rules about how $P(S)$ and $P(S')$ are related where $S$ and $S'$ are (for example) statements such that $S'$ follows from $S$ by applying a rule of inference.  Of course $P(S)$ should also depend on the length of $S$, falling off to zero as $S$ gets too large.

I haven't seen anyone try to carry out such a program in full detail; if you're interested then I think it would make for an interesting project.  There has been some work done by logicians on formalizing vagueness that might be relevant.

Comment: Perhaps computational cost is a better model here than probability, with some calculus on assertions such as "I can affirm $S$ after $N$ units of computation", and impredicative induction having an infinite computational cost.

Comment: @TimothyChow First of all, only my first question has been answered; I'm still in search of a computable nonstandard model that has the properties I want.  Second of all, I think you're mischaracterizing Nelson's viewpoint; he's not being vague at all. To be clear, it's not like he believes there are only finitely many natural numbers. He believes every natural number has a successor, and he believes that the numbers are closed under addition and multiplication. When he says he doesn't think exponentiation is total, all he means is that $a^b$ can be infinite even though $a$ and $b$ are finite.

Comment: @TimothyChow (cont'd) And there's no need to assign probabilities to what statements of arithmetic he'll accept; it's an entirely deterministic matter.  He'll accept whatever can be proven in extensions of Robinson's $Q$, specifically weak schemes of induction, which are interpretable in $Q$ itself.  From the point of view of classical mathematics, here is a precise characterization of his views: Nelson accepts all the bounded sentences which are consequences of $I \Delta_0$ + the assumption that exponentiation is total, where $I \Delta_0$ is $Q$ + induction on bounded formulas.

Comment: @TimothyChow (cont'd) Of course, Nelson would dispute the latter characterization, because he believes that exponentiation is NOT total, and is actively trying to prove that, but assuming classical mathematics is in fact correct, that is how we can characterize the set of arithmetic sentences that he believes in.

Comment: @Keshav: The vagueness I'm referring to is the vagueness of what the largest integer is. When you say that he doesn't believe that there are only finitely many natural numbers...well, look at what you quoted: He says that
perhaps there is no such number as 80^5000. Not that 80^5000 is infinitely large. He only says that we can't say for sure that 80^5000 is finite. The source of Nelson's
skepticism is the physical infeasibility of arbitrarily large integers, and physical infeasibility is a vague concept. That's what I mean by vagueness; I don't mean Nelson is unclear about what he believes.

Comment: Also when you say that he'll accept whatever can be proven in $Q$, I agree that he'll accept statements whose proofs in $Q$ can be exhibited, but most mathematicians will say that there are theorems of Q that are 80^5000 characters long, but I don't think Nelson will agree. When Nelson says he accepts that the successor of a natural number is a natural number, we have to be careful not to assume that he means exactly what we mean by that.  He's willing to assert any explicitly exhibited theorem of $Q$, but that's not the same as what most people mean by accepting $Q$.

Comment: @TimothyChow It's easy to misunderstand Nelson's views, because they're so extreme, but he definitely doesn't believe in a largest integer. He believes that the sequence 1, 1+1, 1+1+1, ... goes on for all eternity. But he believes that there are some numbers $a$ and $b$ in this sequence such that $a^b$ never occurs in the sequence, even though if $a$ and $b$ occur in the sequence, $a + b$ and $ab$ must occur in the sequence. Now you or I may think this is impossible, because if $2^x$ is infinite, then there must be a least number $n$ such that $2^n$ is infinite, but that assumes induction.

Comment: @TimothyChow The reason for Nelson's skepticism about large numbers like $2^{2^{2^5}}$ is NOT that he thinks that numbers that are too physically infeasible are meaningless.  Rather, he's skeptical about the expression $2^{2^{2^5}}$, because it would be physically infeasible for someone to prove that $2^{2^{2^5}}$ is in fact of the form $1 + 1 + 1 + ... + 1$ for some number of $1$'s, so we don't know for sure that $2^{2^{2^{2^5}}}$ does in fact occur somewhere in the sequence $1, 1+1, 1+1+1, ...$. So it's not a skepticism of large numbers per se, but of expressions claimed to be numbers.

Comment: @TimothyChow The only reason why Nelson may be skeptical about there being theorems with proofs $80^{5000}$ lines long is because he's skeptical there's such a thing as "$80^{5000}$ lines long", but he thinks there's a 1 line proof, a 1+1 line proof, a 1+1+1 line proof etc. As far as what it means to "believe in $Q$", if you don't like how I phrased that, let me put it as a theorem of classical mathematics: for any sentence $S$, Ed Nelson will accept $S$ if he lives for a sufficiently long time $t$ if and only if $S$ is a bounded consequence of $Q$ + bounded induction + exponentiation is total

Comment: @Keshav: Though I'm not sure I agree with your interpretation of Nelson, let me set that aside for a moment.  In what sense does a nonstandard model illustrate Nelson's point of view?  Nelson doesn't believe in the completed totality of the natural numbers, so he wouldn't believe in your nonstandard model either.  Are you just looking for something that illustrates a small subset of Nelson's beliefs, namely those surrounding his beliefs about the totality (or otherwise) of exponentiation?

Comment: @TimothyChow What exactly do you disagree with in what I said about Nelson?  As far as what I'm after, I'm looking for a computable nonstandard model of arithmetic that illustrates *to the rest of us* what Edward Nelson believes.  Obviously Nelson himself wouldn't find such a model acceptable, for the reason you gave.  It's similar to the characterization I gave of the set of arithmetical sentences Nelson would be willing to accept: Nelson himself wouldn't be willing to accept that characterization, but it illustrates what he's doing from the vantage point of classical mathematics.

Comment: @Keshav: We should probably take this discussion offline, but as a sample disagreement, I don't think Nelson thinks the (alleged) totality of multiplication is qualitatively different from the (alleged) totality of exponentiation. It is perfectly feasible to write 1+1+...+1 (eighty times) and to repeat this expression 5000 times with multiplication symbols in between. The result is a notation using only + and * and no exponentiation. Yet Nelson would question whether this expression denotes a finite number.

Comment: @TimothyChow I think if you actually wrote out (1+1+1+...+1) 5000 times with multiplication signs in between, Nelson would accept that expression, and would accept that 80^5000 is finite.  His real problem is with expressions of the form $x^y$ where it's either infeasible to write out $x$ in 1's at all, or it's infeasible to write out $x$ in 1's $y$ times.  But if you actually wrote an expression with 1's and addition and multiplication symbols, Nelson would definitely accept such an expression as valid.

Comment: "finite sets have sharp boundaries" - even in weak, nonclassical logics, where the notions of 'finite' bifurcate?

Comment: @DavidRoberts Edward Nelson fully accepts classical logic and the law of excluded middle.  He has no reason to reject such things, because he's not actually an ultrafinitist in the sense of believing that there are only finitely many natural numbers; indeed, he believes that every number has a successor. He just happens to not believe the the exponentiation of two finite numbers must be finite, (although he does believe that the sum and product of two finite numbers must be finite).  You or I might find that crazy, but he defends it vehemently and skillfully (considering what he has to defend)

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: I think your comments on "crazy" show you to have misunderstood quite a lot.  The distinction on predicativity he makes are clear, and he gives clear reasons.  Existence of numbers is found in a new construction of them, not in a selection from a pre-existing set.  We can't build numbers by ranging over them all.  This may have many different metasemantic origins, but is a general statement among most hard finitists and ultrafinitists.  It's why predicativity is important.  It's an attempt to make numbers meaningful, instead of assumed.  See pages 1-2 and 173-180 of his book

Comment: @ex0du5 I have actually studied Nelson's work in some detail, having read his book and most of his papers on the subject.  I wasn't trying to say that he doesn't have a coherent belief system.  All I meant is that his views would be considered crazy from the Platonistic vantage point.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan: Then you do no justice to your understanding by adding exclamation marks after the point that exponentiation is not total in these systems.  As even he points out, it is not total on modern computers.  And finite computation does indeed provide a basis for models of predicative systems like Q*.  However, as noted in the literature, you need to express such models with functions that restrict intermediate proof stages on notions of "surveyability" and other finiteness constraints.

Comment: ex0du5, what does not being total on modern computers have to do with anything?  The successor function isn't total on modern computers either.

Comment: @ex0du5 I put exclamation points because this would be an absolutely shocking notion to a Platonistic mathematician.  As far as modern computers, do you mean that if you have a modern computer of a fixed, finite size and you ran it for a fixed, finite time, then it wouldn't calculate $a^b$ for all $a$ and $b$?  If that's what you mean, then you're right that exponentiation is not total for modern computers, but then as Timothy Chow  points out, neither are successor, addition, or multiplication.

Comment: @ex0du5 Just to reiterate, I'm not saying that Nelson's worldview is incoherent, he has well-thought out reasons for believing that addition and multiplication are total while exponentiation is not, involving the Hilbert-Ackerman quantifier elimination theorem and relativizarion schemes.  But those reasons are not as simple as you make them seem when you make reference to "modern computers".

Comment: I am sure you are aware of these works, but just in case you are not let me mention that you may find the following paper by Dan Williard [An exploration of the partial respects in which an axiom system recognizing solely addition as a total function can verify its own consistency](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/38338950_An_exploration_of_the_partial_respects_in_which_an_axiom_system_recognizing_solely_addition_as_a_total_function_can_verify_its_own_consistency) interesting.

Answer (score 8):

One way would be to consider the theory consisting of the axioms of arithmetic plus a new symbol $x$ and the axioms $x>1$ and $x^n<2^x$ for each standard natural number $n$. This is consistent, because each finite subset of its axioms is satisfiable. Take a model, and take the initial segment of all numbers less than $x^n$ for some $n$. This is clearly closed under addition and multiplication, but not exponentiation.

I'm not sure how to make a computable model of this theory.